# Add elements in a while loop JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I'm trying to make a while loop that contains two if statements and I don't want to increment until those are done. How would I go by to solve this issue, now the page freezes when I implement the while loop.

```
var task = 0;
while(task < 3) {
  //Enter the title and url and add it to site
  if(window.location.href.indexOf("website.com") > -1) {
    $("input[name=Title]").val(GM_getValue("title" + task));
    $("input[name=SvURL-1]").val(GM_getValue("url" + task));
    $( 'button[name=submit]' ).click();
  }

  //Enters the imdbid to the stream
  if(window.location.href.indexOf("anotherwebsite.com") > -1) {
    console.log($("input[name=EmbedID]").val());
    console.log(GM_getValue("imdid" + task));

    if ($("input[name=EmbedID]").val() != GM_getValue("imdid" + task)) {
      $( "a[data-target=#EditURL]" ).click();
      $("input[name=EmbedID]").attr("value", GM_getValue("imdid" + task));

      setTimeout(function(){ 
        $( 'button:contains("Ok")' ).click();
      }, 1000);

      setTimeout(function(){ 
        $( 'button[name=submit]' ).click();
      }, 1000);

    } else {
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        window.location.replace("https://website.com");
      }, 1000);
      task++;
      alert("task when done: " + task);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you should add greasemonkey as a tag, because you're using GM_* functions

Comment: `if(window.location.href.indexOf("website.com") > -1)`  so if this is false, task will never increase.. that might explain your freezing.

Comment: you are submitting a form in the body of both of the if statements, right? So this shell work cross site / request?

Comment: You should handle this synchronously instead of asynchronously. It must go through that loop a million times before `task` is even incremented by 1.

Comment: please provide a minimal html markup. Furthermore describe a step by step example of what do you want to happen and what contains the storage at which moment? Are there multiple site Requests (reloads) or ajax calls when submitting the form? One more problem: you're in a infinity loop if the domain is already `website.com` but it's also if it's not... so it's everytime an infinity loop

Comment: The script is for two sites on the same domain. The basic function of the script that i want is when all the if statements have been fulfilled and forms submitted I want to increase the task value and do it over again.

Comment: The point is to edit elements and submit then another element on another site. Then I want to do it again but with other elements, that is what increases after each loop.

Comment: `if(window.location.href.indexOf("anotherwebsite.com") > -1) ` is falsey then increment never goes up. Why not, simply use `if(location.match(/^(website|anotherwebsite)\.com$/)` for both? Yes, you can leave off `window.` and `.href`. Why a condition on the increment?

Comment: I use the indexOf because the end of the website is changing depending on which item im editing. Does location.match work with just a part of the website name?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you're only incrementing the variable **task** when a certain condition is met. But since you're inside a while loop, if none of the conditions are met for the variable **task** to increment, then the while loop will not exit. Thus explains the freezing of the page.

What you can do is something like this:

```
var flag = false;
var task = 0;

while (task < 3) {
  if (condition) {
    // some code here...
  }

  if (condition) {
    if (condition) {
      // some code here...    
    } else {
      // some code here...
      flag = true;
    }
  }
  task++;
}

if (flag) {
  // do something here...
}
```

Comment: This was not quite the soloution i was looking for, the task is used in the if statements.

Comment: Okay. Then I would suggest answering the questions of Joshua K. To re-iterate:

1. Can you provide the minimum amount of HTML so that people can at least some have idea on which context your sample code will run.

2. What does **$( 'button[name=submit]' ).click()** do? Does it trigger an event handler that then do an asynchronous job? Does it submit a form? (which if it does, it will force a page reload and the rest of your code will not be executed.)

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest to go with a method & call the method.

Something like this

```js
var task = 0;
var taskMethod = function(){
  //Enter the title and url and add it to site
  if(window.location.href.indexOf("website.com") > -1) {
    $("input[name=Title]").val(GM_getValue("title" + task));
    $("input[name=SvURL-1]").val(GM_getValue("url" + task));

    $( 'button[name=submit]' ).click();
  }

  //Enters the imdbid to the stream
  if(window.location.href.indexOf("anotherwebsite.com") > -1) {
    console.log($("input[name=EmbedID]").val());
    console.log(GM_getValue("imdid" + task));

    if ($("input[name=EmbedID]").val() != GM_getValue("imdid" + task)) {
      $( "a[data-target=#EditURL]" ).click();
      $("input[name=EmbedID]").attr("value", GM_getValue("imdid" + task));

      setTimeout(function(){ $( 'button:contains("Ok")' ).click();}, 1000);
      setTimeout(function(){ $( 'button[name=submit]' ).click();}, 1000);
    } else {
      setTimeout(function(){ window.location.replace("https://website.com");}, 1000);
      task++;
      console.log("task when done: " + task);
      if(task < 3)
        taskMethod();
    }
  }
}

//Initial (First Time) method call
taskMethod();
```

Hope this will help you.